# AureliaJS for long-lasting project

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I'm wondering about framework choice, for an app I want to maintain for years. By maintain I mean mainly continious developing and upgrading. My problem is that AureliaJS is more friendly and nice to work with tool, comparing to Angular 4. But the current version of Aurelia is mere 0.32 and I worry that in the future there could be a lot of backward incompatibile editions. Could anyone experienced JS developer advice me with that choice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love Aurelia. It is my choice for my personal projects. The company I work for has chosen Angular 4 before I joined. I can understand their decision as it's easier to find programmers. Bear in mind that Angular made a dramatic change when they came out with version 2. Completely incompatible. So I believe the risk of breaking changes originates from the success of the current version. It seems that aurelia is taking the right path of sticking

Comment: ...with web standards. Aurelia is light weight and very intuitive compared with Angular. The only wish is to see Aurelia gaining popularity and selected by some prominent organizations.

Comment: Aurelia hit the version 1.0 a year ago - http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/07/27/aurelia-1-0-is-here/. Only CLI is in version 0.31.1 at the moment, but its development started more recently. Now that they have been added Webpack 3 support to it (http://blog.aurelia.io/2017/08/18/aurelia-cli-webpack-update/), I expect that it will get the beta release soon.
From my perspective, Aurelia is a great and mature framework and an excellent choice. Expect this question to be closed though since it's opinionated.

Comment: IMHO, Aurelia is the way to go for a project like you are asking about.

Comment: Have you looked at Vue?

Comment: Vue is also my framework of choice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an Angular Developer, I think Angular is Awesome for long-lasting projects for many reasons

1. **Support:** it is supported by Google, It use **Typescript** as a core language for developing your application which is supported by Microsoft.
2. **Huge Community:** Angular has big community at the time of writing this answer Angular repository has **27095 star** at GitHub, **497 Contributor** while Aurelia has **9984 star** and just **88 contributor**
3. **Cutting Edge Features:** By talking about features Angular follow cutting edge trends in front-end world such as **AOT: Ahead of Time Compilation** , **Universal Angular Apps** which implement server-side rendering to increase the performance of angular app and bring SEO to Single Page Application.
4. **Angular CLI:** Also Angular has cli (Command Line Interface) which make developer life easy by enable scaffolding new application and make components, services and other stuff easier.
5. **Global Events:** Angular has Conferences that take place regularly in many countries.
6. **Used by Big Brands:** many big up and running web applications use Angular for their Apps such as [Freelancer.com](http://freelancer.com)
7. **Used to Develop Multi-Platform App:** with Angular you can make web applications, webview mbile applications using **Ionic** native mobile applications using **NativeScript**, Cross-Platform Desktop Applications using **Electron**
8. **Regular Versions:** Angular has regular versions every 6 months there is new major version, with backward compatibility with old version

I don't have experience in another modern javascript framework so I can't compare angular with another framework, but I think Angular is a Good Choice for the reasons I have Provided

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Angular and React developer at workplace but I have used Aurelia for my personal projects and i can confidently say that the learning curve is easy and fast compared to Angular

If I had to start a project, Aurelia would be my first choice

I also enrolled in Aurelia course at pluralsight which helped me a lot. Another place to look for is www.danyow.net

I hope that corporations start adopting Aurelia just as much as React and Angular